# create smooth exit to the side animation css Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, slider

I need to create an icon menu in which every x seconds all icons move to the left, a new one comes in and the leftmost one goes out.
I Set an interval but I am having a problem finding the logic to make them all move, in order to change between icons I use display and move the divs but I have not yet found the way to animate it correctly.

I have tried this:

```
var icons = jQuery(".search-icon");
icons.first().fadeOut("fast")
icons.eq(6).fadeIn("fast")
jQuery(".icons-row").animate({left: "+=110px"},{duration:300, queue:false,done:function(){
    jQuery(".icons-row").css("left","0");
    icons.first().insertAfter(icons.last());
    icons.css("display","inline");
    icons.slice(-5).css("display","none");
    icons.first().css("display","none")
}});
```

The idea was that ill move them all and make the one on the right fade while bringing in one on the left and then put them immediately back in place Theoretically without it being noticed but adding another element changes the location of the icons until I take the last one out and that means it doesn't look right.

Is there an easier simpler way to do this?

HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="quick-search-icons">
    <a class="prev" onclick="switchforward()">&#10094;</a>
    <div class="icons-row" style="position: relative">
    <div class="search-icon" id="animated-n">
        details
    </div>
    <div class="search-icon" id="animated-n">
        details
    </div>
    <div class="search-icon" id="animated-n">
        details
    </div>
    <div class="search-icon" id="animated-n">
        details
    </div>
    <div class="search-icon" id="animated-n">
        details
    </div>
    <div class="search-icon" id="animated-n">
        details
    </div>
    <div class="search-icon" id="animated-n">
        details
    </div>
    <div class="search-icon" id="animated-n">
        details
    </div>
    <div class="search-icon" id="animated-n">
        details
    </div>
    <div class="search-icon" id="animated-n">
        details
    </div>
    <div class="search-icon" id="animated-n">
        details
    </div>
    <div class="search-icon" id="animated-n">
        details
    </div>
    </div>
    <a class="next" onclick="switchbackward()">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you add a simplified version of the html in http://jsfiddle.net so we can duplicate the issue you are seeing and play around with it. At least for me it's hard to see what's going on without an example

Comment: @Huangism Added the html code of the structure